# evaluation of determinant without expanding

Tags: determinant

If $\;\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & x & x & x \\
  x & b & x & x \\
  x & x & c & x \\
  x & x & x & d
\end{pmatrix}
=f(x)-xf’(x)$

where $f'(x)$ denotes the derivative of $f(x)$ w.r.t. $x$, then $f(x)$ is equal to

$(a) \quad (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$

$(b) \quad (x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)$

$(c) \quad 2(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$

$(d) \quad 2(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)$

I have tried using the properties of determinant to get the determinant in the form of
$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & x & x & x \\
  0 & b-x & x-c & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & c-x & x-d \\
  x-a & 0 & 0 & d-x
\end{pmatrix}$$

which is equal to 
$a \det
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & x & x \\
  b-x & x-c & 0 \\
  0 & c-x & x-d
\end{pmatrix}
+(a-x)\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & x & x \\
  b-x & x-c & 0 \\
  0 & c-x & x-d
\end{pmatrix}$

which seems difficult to evaluate knowing that it is a objective problem there must be some way out. Please help me with this one.

Comment: Every time you format a question like this, a kitten sheds a tear. Please see the help center for **proper** formatting.

Comment: I can't even begin to read this disaster.

Comment: Please, for the sake of the kittens, read our [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You applied wrong Laplace expansion. You must **eliminate** the corresponding row. In fact, the first $(3\times 3)$ matrix should be upper triangular.

Answer (score 0):

### This is not a rigorous proof:

Substitute $x=0$, we have

$$f(0)=abcd$$

Substitute $x=a$, we have

$$f(a)-af'(a)=-a(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)$$

We'll have similar expressions for $x=b$, etc.

> Considering
>
> $$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$$

which gives  $f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)=(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)$ and matches all conditions.

**P.S.:**
The general solution is $$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)+k x$$